# check array element in PHP

Tags: php

Could PHP check if a certain element in the array contains some words?

for example :

```
        `[order_product_code] => I9300_cash397096569`
```

want to check if the element contains cash word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `$array` is your array of element:

```
foreach($array as $key=>$element) {
  if(strpos('cash',$element) !== FALSE) echo "$key: ok";
  else echo "$key: ko";
}
```

Comment: It's better to do `if(strpos($needle, $haystack) !== FALSE)`.

Comment: @AmalMurali: you're right